# how to show interstitial add in managed expo app?

Tags: react-native, admob, expo, interstitial

I want to add interstitial ad on my expo managed app. So as described in the expo documentation https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/admob/  I have implemented the code. But it gives me the following warning.

[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Native method ExpoAdsAdMobInterstitialManager.requestAd expects 0 arguments but received 1]

the banner ad is working fine

```
showInterstitial = async () => {
    AdMobInterstitial.setAdUnitID('ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');// my ad unit id
    AdMobInterstitial.setTestDeviceID('EMULATOR');
    await AdMobInterstitial.requestAdAsync({ servePersonalizedAds: true });
    await AdMobInterstitial.showAdAsync();
  }
```

Comment: Can you post app.json and package.json files?

Comment: @Oleg I have upgraded the expo version from 34.0.0 to 35.0.0 and it worked.